# google app engine cloud endpoint security

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am starting a new project and using javascript based UI as fronted and google cloud endpoints backed by google datastore for data storage.

I don't need to use any of the google services for user login etc. In other words, i will have my own table to store username, pwd and other profile info.

So, the questions are:
1. How will my service based frontend will hold the session?
2. How will it understand that requests are going for which user account to return user specific data?

Also to start with, I have so far created an endpoint which basically returns true or false on passing username to it. (just to mimic valid user or not).

The question is do i really need to configure any security to invoke this api from the javascript client i have?

Comment: If you're rolling your own authentication, you'll have to write your own authentication/authorization layer.

Comment: and what is the way to use existing authentication but using my own set username passwords?

Comment: If you're using Flask or Django, possibly. In Django you could import them into its own database, or make a custom authentication backend. With flask, you could integrate flask-login, or flask-security. I'm not aware of any such feature in webapp2. (edit: Or in endpoints, I'm also not aware of any such feature.)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to use custom usernames and passwords, you'll need more than just a process to send and retrieve this data from your endpoint.

Consider using something that's there already. E.g. webapp2 has a basic auth module which allows you to have your own database with usernames and passwords but already has many required security measures in place.

A tutorial I've used to implement this in the past: https://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: its for python. i need for java

Answer (score 1):

So the basic answer is Google Cloud Endpoints is best suited for applications which users google accounts as authentication mechanism.

So if you are using cloud endpoints, and wanted to have custom authentication mechanism, you have to create your own.

**How will my service based frontend will hold the session?**

Upon successful authentication (by any form either user credentials, third party social login etc), you need to setup session for that user eg; by using session cookies.

**How will it understand that requests are going for which user account to return user specific data?**

Cloud Endpoint cannot tell that, so you have to write an custom filter or interceptor to check if valid session or cookie exists and either reject or continue the request.

To pass the current authenticated user who is requesting the api, you need to inject the user informations somehow (using DI, or request properties etc) into the ApiEndpoints, so with that you can process the request accordingly

Comment: so if i dont go with my own security layer and rely on google's then does my end user have to have a google account to use my site?

Comment: Yes, that's right , but the decision should be made based on what your application what's rather than what appengine provides , if your business need custom authentication then you should go and built your own